# iOS - Crash on [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO] Deallocated error

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I have a crash on `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES]` located in my viewWillAppear when I come back to the UIViewController using that toolbar. With this Error `*** -[CALayer retain]: Message sent to deallocated instace 0x5d0e0a0` I am not expressly releasing the toolbar but the class where I am setting it is autoreleased.

Also am I incorrect in assuming that the toolbar is on the navigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a cheap and easy way to get this to work.

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retain a reference to the toolbar in the navigation controller in which it appears. You should **not** set UI interfaces in transient classes. It is important to separate your models from the views via a controller - thus "Model-View-Controller" design pattern.

A tool bar does not necessitate a navigation controller. Do not confound with a navigation bar, which can be sort of similar.

Comment: I did think about using a regular toolbar but my app uses image sequences which overlay the whole UIViewController necessitating the toolbar being above that view controller which the Nav Controller Toolbar works perfectly for. However even if I move the toolbar manipulation onto the AppDelegate it is still crashing.

Comment: And as a side note I am not mistaken the UINavigationController it also has a toolbar embedded with it.

Comment: -- mistaken, unfortunately. ;-)